# SSIS in Azure: operation_messages_scaleout event_messages_scaleout tables not populating

Tags: ssis, logs

We are running SSIS packages in AZure. I am finding that for some reason we have stopped populating the SSISDB tables (operation_messages_scaleout, event_messages_scaleout). It does appear that the operations table is being populated. It does not matter if the execution succeeds or fails.
Is there a setting that turns this on/off? It was working for a long time, but it just stopped working one morning when the next daily execution started up.
[image: All Executions]

[image: Messages]